# How to automaticaly setState in an onChange event in a select-dropdown, as currently the event is triggered only when the user clicks on the list?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, the default state is empty and is updated only when the user clicks on the drop-down triggering the `onChange` event. How do I make it so that the item selected by default is also set to the state? So the first option is selected by default in the drop-down, and I'd like to set the first option in the state automatically.

```
this.state = { slug: '' }

<select>
    data && data.map((datum, i) => { return (
    <option
         value={datum.id}
         key={i}
         onChange={e => this.setState({ slug: datum.slug })}>
             {datum.name}
    </option>
    )})}
<select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the default value in the state
this.state = { slug: 'zero' }

and then tells react to set that value in the `select`

```
<select value={this.state.slug}>
  <option value="zero">Zero</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

If you want to programmatically select the first value, you can write this.

```
<select>
    data && data.map((datum, i) => { 
    const isSelected = this.state.slug === '' && i === 0;
    return (
        <option
            selected={isSelected}
            value={datum.id}
            key={i}
            onChange={}
        >
           {datum.name}
        </option>
     )})}
</selected>
```

If you want your state to reflect your default option, you can do that in the `constructor` of the component.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        slug : this.props.data[0].id
    }
}
```

After that you can use one of the solutions I mention before to handling the `select` component.

If you change `data` often, you can do that inside `componentWillReceiveProps` instead of `constructor`, but the idea it's the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm trying to do. My list is `changeable` so it is not possible to define a default state, so it must remain be empty by default. Since the browser lists the first item in the list by default, the best option would be to `set the first item` automatically in the state. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't work. This is just for selecting the first item in the list (which happens by default), not to `setState` the first item.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question, I edited again the answer, maybe I got it this time :D

Comment: That's so axiomatic. Thanks a lot, Max.

Comment: happy that I got your answer at the end @anonym